# How to load faster images for Machine learning

Tags: python, url, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am having a dataset for about 50k images, i have to get these images from URL , convert them to an array and use them in my machine learning algorithm.

Here is my code to fetch the image.

```
        import requests
        from io import BytesIO
        from PIL import Image,ImageFile
        import validators
        import urllib, cStringIO,urllib2

  def get_pixel(img_path):
    ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
    if(validators.url(img_path)==True):
       img = Image.open(urllib2.urlopen(img_path))
       img= img.resize((64,64))
       x = image.img_to_array(img)
       x = preprocess_input(x)
       return x
```

Finally calling this code to get my training set

```
X = Data['Link_to_the_image'].apply(lambda x:get_pixel(x))
```

But this method is too slow, it has been more than 1 hour and still it's not yet complete. Can someone suggest me effective and efficient way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking a long time because you are doing each request sequentially. It would probably be better to use some concurrency/parallelism to speed up the process.

I'd recommend starting out with some like *asynchronous requests* (see [link to docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests)):

```
from requests import async  # you will need the module gevent

rs = [async.get(u) for u in URL_LIST]
```

For this you'll have to break your function a bit (or process the dataframe by chunks) so that you can parsing more then one image at a time (or at least, the requests part, which seems to be the slowest).

Let me know if you need more guidance.